# Why is quroum 7 nodes example creating genesis block for every node

Tags: quorum

I tried the Quorum 7 nodes example and it worked flawlesly. but what i found out is that running the `./raft-init.sh` a genesis block is being written for every node.

**Code :**

```
[*] Configuring node 1 (permissioned)
INFO [03-07|09:47:20] Maximum peer count                       ETH=25 LES=0 total=25
INFO [03-07|09:47:20] Allocated cache and file handles         database=/home/ronin/Desktop/testQuorum/quorum-examples/examples/7nodes/qdata/dd1/geth/chaindata cache=16 handles=16
INFO [03-07|09:47:20] Writing custom genesis block 
INFO [03-07|09:47:20] Persisted trie from memory database      nodes=0 size=0.00B time=2.896µs gcnodes=0 gcsize=0.00B gctime=0s livenodes=1 livesize=0.00B
INFO [03-07|09:47:20] Successfully wrote genesis state         database=chaindata                                                                               hash=c23b4e…8b1b71
INFO [03-07|09:47:20] Allocated cache and file handles         database=/home/ronin/Desktop/testQuorum/quorum-examples/examples/7nodes/qdata/dd1/geth/lightchaindata cache=16 handles=16
INFO [03-07|09:47:20] Writing custom genesis block 
INFO [03-07|09:47:20] Persisted trie from memory database      nodes=0 size=0.00B time=2.534µs gcnodes=0 gcsize=0.00B gctime=0s livenodes=1 livesize=0.00B
INFO [03-07|09:47:20] Successfully wrote genesis state         database=lightchaindata                                                                               hash=c23b4e…8b1b71
[*] Configuring node 2 (permissioned)
INFO [03-07|09:47:20] Maximum peer count                       ETH=25 LES=0 total=25
INFO [03-07|09:47:20] Allocated cache and file handles         database=/home/ronin/Desktop/testQuorum/quorum-examples/examples/7nodes/qdata/dd2/geth/chaindata cache=16 handles=16
INFO [03-07|09:47:21] Writing custom genesis block 
INFO [03-07|09:47:21] Persisted trie from memory database      nodes=0 size=0.00B time=5.99µs gcnodes=0 gcsize=0.00B gctime=0s livenodes=1 livesize=0.00B
INFO [03-07|09:47:21] Successfully wrote genesis state         database=chaindata                                                                               hash=c23b4e…8b1b71
INFO [03-07|09:47:21] Allocated cache and file handles         database=/home/ronin/Desktop/testQuorum/quorum-examples/examples/7nodes/qdata/dd2/geth/lightchaindata cache=16 handles=16
INFO [03-07|09:47:21] Writing custom genesis block 
INFO [03-07|09:47:21] Persisted trie from memory database      nodes=0 size=0.00B time=5.137µs gcnodes=0 gcsize=0.00B gctime=0s livenodes=1 livesize=0.00B
INFO [03-07|09:47:21] Successfully wrote genesis state         database=lightchaindata                                                                               hash=c23b4e…8b1b71
[*] Configuring node 3 (permissioned)
INFO [03-07|09:47:21] Maximum peer count                       ETH=25 LES=0 total=25
INFO [03-07|09:47:21] Allocated cache and file handles         database=/home/ronin/Desktop/testQuorum/quorum-examples/examples/7nodes/qdata/dd3/geth/chaindata cache=16 handles=16
INFO [03-07|09:47:21] Writing custom genesis block 
INFO [03-07|09:47:21] Persisted trie from memory database      nodes=0 size=0.00B time=1.706µs gcnodes=0 gcsize=0.00B gctime=0s livenodes=1 livesize=0.00B
INFO [03-07|09:47:21] Successfully wrote genesis state         database=chaindata                                                                               hash=c23b4e…8b1b71
INFO [03-07|09:47:21] Allocated cache and file handles         database=/home/ronin/Desktop/testQuorum/quorum-examples/examples/7nodes/qdata/dd3/geth/lightchaindata cache=16 handles=16
INFO [03-07|09:47:21] Writing custom genesis block 
INFO [03-07|09:47:21] Persisted trie from memory database      nodes=0 size=0.00B time=2.491µs gcnodes=0 gcsize=0.00B gctime=0s livenodes=1 livesize=0.00B
INFO [03-07|09:47:21] Successfully wrote genesis state         database=lightchaindata                                                                               hash=c23b4e…8b1b71
```

As you can see `Writing genesis block` is being done for every node. So does everynode has a blockchain on its own ? isn't the 7 nodes example supposed to show how 7 different nodes with different "Responsibilities" coexist and function with one blockchain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
geth --datadir qdata/dd1 init genesis.json
geth --datadir qdata/dd2 init genesis.json
geth --datadir qdata/dd3 init genesis.json
```

and so on.....

This is the same genesis file that it is using to initialize. It is not different hence not a different blockchain.

You are on the same chain if 1. You have the same network ID 2. Your genesis block is exactly the same and you are peers with the other nodes with this net ID

Comment: That is quite late, I figured that out myself actually. thanks anyway.